# Inject a set of strings (not properties) from a file on file system at app startup

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

At application boot-up, I want to read a set of strings from a file in this simple format:

```
y
yes
t
true
run
trade
t
```

and inject it into one of my service classes, e.g. using Spring dependency injection. I'm currently reading properties files using:

```
<util: id="imapConfig" 
  location="file:#{systemEnvironment['MY_PROPS']}/imap-config.properties" />
```

or

```
<bean id="imapConfig"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="location" 
    value="file:#{systemEnvironment['MY_PROPS']}/imap-extra.properties" />
</bean>
```

so I know it would be easy to work around the issue by changing the list file to a properties file:

```
=y
=t
=true
=etc...
```

and then just calling `props.getValues()` or similar.

Is there a cleaner way?